# Laravel Blade adds unwanted spaces in final HTML

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm developing views in Laravel Blade and I always get unwanted spaces in the final HTML (checking with Dev tool) like this (ugly case):

[image]

You'll see a lot of unwanted spaces, where the code is simply:

```
<!-- Ugly -->  
<div>
  Lorem ipsum
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously I've tabulation set as spaces in my IDE.

I tried to remove them in many ways where the only one that works is to put all inline:

```
<!-- Beautiful (but I can't do this for all!) -->
<div>Lorem ipsum<div>Lorem ipsum</div></div>
```

but very often **I can't do that**.

How can avoid all these spaces?

EDIT: **this seems to happens in Chrome**, not in Firefox

Comment: There must be white spaces in your code. either in your `main.blade.php` or in your extended views. Please do check that as well.

Comment: @HassaanAli There isn't!

Comment: The first snippet of HTML you have shown us clearly has whitespace around the text ... and as you found yourself, removing them removes the spaces.  Does the whitespace show up in the browser, or only in the source?  Devtools does not necessarily render things exactly as they appear in the source - have you checked the source as well?

Comment: try using span tag around your content otherwise you won't be able to get ride of it...
Or you can also search for a package who can help you get ride of tabs and double spaces in the cached views ...

Comment: @Don'tPanic good point, but my source appears like this https://i.postimg.cc/sfvq5mSN/source.jpg Not what I'd call a beauty! :( Obviously my code is all tidy, well indented and tabulation with spaces

Comment: Updated the question with more info

Comment: The screenshots from devtools - devtools does not reflect exactly how the source looks.  If you're worried about this, refer to the source, not devtools.  Whitespace from your Blade templates all ends up in your HTML, so if you have nicely indented an `<section>` with a nested `@include`, that indent is in your source.  Likewise for all Blade directives, `@if`, `@foreach`, etc etc - the whitespace used to format your *code* ends up mis-formatting your HTML source.  You can remove the formatting in your code, but that's a poor trade-off.  The bigger question is why worry about it? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am noticing this as well. There is interaction between the blade directives and the output formatting/whitespace.

I think what is going on is that the breakpoints in the rendered php occur at the line position of the blade directives. I think this is effectively the desired behaviour though as it is the same behaviour I notice if I use `<?php ?>` breaks in place of the blade directives.

The way I have worked around this pre-laravel was to zero-indent the `<?php ?>` breaks, which effectively re-zeros the indent for the contents generated within the `<?php ?>` braces. This works well and is the most logical way I have found to precisely control the output whitespace from a code readability perspective (though not perfect!).

The equivalent in blade-land appears to be to do the same with blade directives, ie. put them on a new line at position zero. This looks a bit irksome (as it does with regular `<?php ?>` breaks) but it is the only way I have found to control the output (and I still find regular php to be easier to read and faster to type out than the blade directives for the most part, where you don't need features like $loop).